# Customize SVG icons in Tilemill/Mapbox

Tags: svg, mapbox, tilemill

I added a data layer on my map and I'm using an svg image to represent the markers.

```
#points {
  point-file: url(marker2.svg);
  marker-width:10;
  marker-fill:#fff;
}
```

since it's an SVG image, I'm trying to customize the fill color but it is not working. `marker-fill` seems to only work on the markers they provide, but not on SVG images. Is this possible to do using TileMill/Mapbox ? Is it possible with the JS API ?

**UPDATE**

From http://mapbox.com/blog/announcing-tilemill-0.10.0/, it looks like using `marker-fill` should have done the trick but that's not the case. Could the problem be with my svg image ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, looks like if you're looking to customize the marker, you need

`marker-file: url(marker2.svg);` instead of  `point-file: url(marker2.svg);`